# Angular service data not getting displayed

Tags: angular, promise, angular-promise, angular7

I try to display a list of object (Users here, but I'll need to display lots of other types) and when I try to follow tutorials, It display nothing on my screen.

Whereas when I launch full built tutorials from Github, it works.

What do I do wrong ?

Here is my code. If you need something else, tell me.

I work in **Angular 7**.

**UserListComponent**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import {UserService} from "../core/user.service";
import {User} from "../model/user.model";
export class UserListComponent implements OnInit {

  users: User[];

  constructor(private router: Router, private userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getUsers()
      .subscribe( data => {
        this.users = data;
      });
  }
}
```

**UserService**

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  baseUrl: string = 'http://localhost:8080/api/user';

  getUsers() {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(this.baseUrl);
  }
}
```

user-list.component.html

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <h2> User Details</h2>
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let user of users">
      <td>{{user.id}}</td>
      <td>{{user.email}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

When I `alert(data[0].mail)` I have the correct mail, but users remains empty when I try to display it

Comment: Do you have an API server running somewhere where you've hosted this: `http://localhost:8080/api/user`

Comment: Hi, yes, when I do alert(data[0].mail); i get a popup with the right mail showing.

Comment: Please update `.html` and imports in `.ts`

Comment: Added html and imports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are receiving users **asynchronously**.
So when the page first renders, Users are not there yet. (Pop up will display after, so they will)

You need to use an async method for the page to know data will be updated after the first render and **re-render**.

```
export class UserListComponent implements OnInit {

  users$: Observable<Users>; // Using Observable

  constructor(private router: Router, private userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.users = this.userService.getUsers()
  }
}
```

As you see, I am using **Observable** prop. This will notify every time it changes.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <h2> User Details</h2>
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let user of users$ | async">
      <td>{{user.id}}</td>
      <td>{{user.email}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

And specifying in the HTML file via **| async** pipe that this prop is async, and is going to update.

*Async pipe:* https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

*Observables:* https://angular.io/guide/observables

Comment: This is a correct answers. Another possibility is to use elvis operators in your template: {{user?.email}} instead of an async pipe..

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works but it doesn't explain why some tutorials I tried worked and my code didn't.

Comment: @Boffbad your tutorials must or user Observables or delay page from the display before data is set, or load data locally (Meaning It's synchronized)